# ¿Cómo hago que imprima el ultimo valor correcto de una comparación de un arreglos de números del promedio?

Tags: c++, array, c, funciones

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #define TAM 5 //Macro

 int numeros[TAM];   //Variable Global - ARREGLO

 float promedio;  //Variable Global - EL PROMEDIO

 void numerosAleatorios(int numeros[], int);

 int promedioNumeros(int numeros[], int);

 void numerosMayores (int numeros[], int, float promedio);

 void Desviacion (int numeros[], int, float promedio);

 void main (void){
     numerosAleatorios(numeros, TAM);
     printf("\n\n");
     promedioNumeros(numeros, TAM);
     printf("\n\n");
     numerosMayores (numeros, TAM, promedio);
     printf("\n\n");
     Desviacion (numeros, TAM, promedio);
     getch();
 }

 //Funcion de generar numeros aleatorios
 void numerosAleatorios(int numeros[], int tam){
     srand (time(NULL));
     int rango=51-10;
     printf ("\t\tNumeros aleatorios dentro del arreglo:\n");
     for(int i=1;i<=TAM;i++){
         numeros[i]=rand ()% rango+10;
         printf("\n\t\tPosicion %d\t->\t%d", i, numeros[i]);
     }
 }

 //Funcion sacar el promedio
 int promedioNumeros(int numeros[], int tam){
     int sumatoria=0;
     printf ("\t\tSumatoria y promedio:\n");
     for(int i=1;i<=TAM;i++){
     sumatoria+=numeros[i];
     }
     printf ("\n\t\tSumatoria:\t%d", sumatoria);
     promedio= (float)sumatoria/TAM;
     printf ("\n\t\tPromedio:\t%g", promedio);
     return promedio;
 }

 //Función determinar los números mayores que el promedio
      void numerosMayores (int numeros[], int tam, float promedio){
     int numerosMayor[TAM], pos=0, i=0;
     printf("\t\t** Los numeros mayores que el promedio y sus posiciones:\n");
     for (i=1;i<=TAM; i++){
         if(numeros[i]>promedio){
             numerosMayor[i] = numeros[i];
             pos=i;
             printf ("\n\t\tPosicion %d = %i", i, numerosMayor[i]);
         }else{
             continue;
         }
     }
 }

     //La desviación de los valores
     void Desviacion (int numeros[], int tam, float promedio){
     int desviacion[TAM];
     printf("\t\tLa desviacion de cada valor:\n");
     for(int i=1;i<=TAM;i++){
          desviacion[i] = numeros[i] - promedio;
          printf ("\n\t\t%d.\tElemento: %d - Desviacion: %3d", i, numeros[i], desviacion[i]);
     }
 }
```

> Le pondré un ejemplo de como me lo compila en CodeBlocks:
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo compila de manera correcta, con los datos correctos pero si lo compilo en Dev C++ o un compilador en línea me cambia solo en el ultimo valor del arreglo en la función `numerosMayores` como también en la función `Desviacion` y me imprime números grandes que ni es el que esta en el arreglo.

Mira a que me refiero: (Compilado en Dev C++)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien esa es mi pregunta, si es por el compilador o es por un error en el código que en CodeBlcok me lo ejecuta bien y en Dev C++ o en un compilador en línea lo ejecuta distinto. Porque quería estar seguro que el código este bien hecho, lo quise probar en otros compiladores a ver si salía bien, como otros códigos que pruebo y si lo compila normal y sin problemas, esto lo hago para estar seguro si los códigos realmente están  bien. Espero que me aclaren eso o corrijan, saludos!.

Comment: que lenguaje es? `c` o `c++`?... más parece `c` pero dices que lo ejecutas en `dev c++`...

Comment: En la ultima imagen lo compilo en **Dev C++**, el tipo de extensión es **cpp**, el lenguaje es **C**.

Comment: `c` en compilador `c`, `c++` en compilador `c++`, si no me equivoco. Aunque lo compilé en mi editor de código en `c` y tengo el resultado de la segunda imagen.

Comment: Ya encontré cual era el problema, si utilizas CodeBlock no tendrás problemas con la impresión, te va a salir como en la primera imagen. Ahora en Dev C++ se puede compilar códigos en lenguaje **C**, lo único que debes cambiar la extensión o sea el tipo de archivo cuando se guarda, en vez de poner **.cpp** solo pones **.c** y listo. Vuelves compilas y ejecutas, entonces se va imprimir como la primera imagen.  En la función principal solo cambia el **Void** a **int** o sea **int main (void)**.

Comment: Claro... cuando cambias de `c` a `c++` tienes que cambiar algunas cosas... pero que bueno que lo haya solucionado, éxitos =).

Comment: Gracias por la atención y la ayuda, de hecho gracias a lo que dijiste sobre que debe compilarse lo de **C** en compilador **C**, hizo que cambiara el tipo de archivo y pudiera compilar y imprimir bien, no recordaba que eso afecta en los resultados cuando son distintas las extensiones jajaja SALUDOS Y GRACIAS.  :D

Comment: @JeremyGonzález Por favor escriba tu solución como solución, y acéptala para marcar el problema como resuelto. Y mira si quieres cambiar el título, ya que no tiene nada que ver con el problema (confusión `.c`/`.cpp`). Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el procedimiento numerosMayores la i del for empieza en 1, cuando debería empezar en 0, ya que los arreglos en C son en base 0.
Si bien la inicializas en 0, la empiezas a recorrer en 1
Quedaría así:

```
for (i=0;i<=TAM; i++){
```

Comment: No es la solución definitiva al problema, pero arregla un bug. Aprovecha que en los comentarios el autor puso cual es el problema para dar la respuesta definitiva;)

Answer (score 0):

En C un array de tamaño `TAM`, tiene `TAM`, elementos. Es decir los índices validos van de 0 a `TAM -1`.

El código del post original escribe en el elemento `TAM`... Debido al `<=` de la comparación en los bucles.

Todos los bucles deberían tener la siguiente forma:

`for (i=0;i<TAM;i++)`....

Lo que sucede es que el acceso de un buffer con un índice fuera de límites (*out-of-bound*), según el standard C es *Undefined behavior*. Lo que esto significa es que el estándar no dice que es lo que hay que hacer y se deja al compilador (bueno al que escribe el compilador) decidir que hacer en esos casos.

Esa es la razón por la que el resultado con los dos compiladores es diferentes.